# Coverting a variable to a function template parameter

Tags: c++

Full disclosure, I know nothing about C++. :-) I have written a chess engine called Myrddin and one of the most used functions is AlphaBeta(), which has Depth as a parameter. Depth can be anywhere from 1-128, and the value of Depth is checked in multiple places inside AlphaBeta(). I received a recommendation from somebody as follows:

> I see a possible improvement: change

```
int AlphaBeta(int Depth, int Alpha, int Beta, PV *Line, BOOL NullMove)
```

> to

```
template<int Depth>
int AlphaBeta(int Alpha, int Beta, PV *Line, BOOL NullMove)
```

> With this change suddenly all ifs that question Depth become runtime free! The check for (Depth > 5) etc will be a constant like 'true' and big parts of code get removed for every node except the leaf node! Every node of every position your engine visits asks about the depth many times. So this adds up a lot.
> Note that to convert a runtime variable like depth to a template at runtime is with one preprocessor generated switch from depth 0 to 128, but this is only called once.

Does this make sense? Can somebody provide some insight into the last sentence, because I don't understand it at all.

Thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't begin optimization by listening to random advice. Profile your code first, see what's actually the slowest part, then tinker with it.

Comment: Most chess engines change depth of search as the game progresses to for example: follow capture sequences, forced moves, at end-game as the branching factor decreases depth can be increased,  etc.  Making `Depth` a compile time constant (in the template version) would stop the `AlphaBeta` function being called for variable depths as the game progresses.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Myrddin is 13 years old now and I've spent a great deal of time over the years on improvements and optimization, within my knowledge sphere, including formal profiling. This was a suggestion that I not only had no idea how to implement, but also if it made any sense at all.

Comment: @RichardCritten Indeed, Depth changes constantly inside the engine throughout a game, but doesn't change within each call to AlphaBeta(). Not sure if that makes sense as a reply to your comment, though.....

Comment: Template parameters are compile time constants ie they are fixed at compile time and  can't be changed at runtime.  If you want to call `AlphaBeta` with different depths which depend on the current game position then that depth is not a something that is known and constant at compile time.  Therefore the templated version of  `AlphaBeta` is not appropriate.  The only way to use the templated version is to have a switch statement with `128` cases (one for each possible depth).  This would cause 128 instantiations of the templated `AlphaBeta` function.

Comment: This advice makes some sense, but I'm not sure how much it'll help. I'd start by adding something like `if (Depth < 0 || Depth > 128) __builtin_unreachable();` to the non-templated version and compare it against the proposed solution. I wouldn't use preprocessor here, templates are enough. Something like this: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/cbYzoje1Y

Comment: Thanks very much, folks. I won't bother with this as I highly doubt the improvement will be measurable.